# iOS Bluetooth dual-mode: How to identify ble and br/edr is same device, when connecte ble to an already connected br/edr headset

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

When iOS connected a bluetooth dual-mode headset on setting--bluetooth, our app wants to connect the same device with ble.
If there is one bluetooth device nearby, It's OK. Our app searches ble devices and identifies our device with bluetooth name(ble name and br/edr name is same and we preset it).
But there are many our dual-mode headsets nearby, We connect headset(br/edr) first on setting. When going app, we can search many same name ble devices.We can't identify which device is the one (br/edr mdoe) had aleady connect my iOS device.If we can get already connected br/edr bluetooth mac address and all ble devices mac address we searched, we can identify it. This method works on Android,but not on iOS.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately Core Bluetooth does not expose the actual MAC address of the Bluetooth device.  It supplies a UUID that is based on the MAC but is an opaque value.  Neither does the AV Framework expose the name or MAC address of connected headset devices.

Comment: When headset(A2DP and HFP) connected, we try to get some information such as mac address, uuid of the headset. But  it seems iOS has not a interface to access br/edr bluetooth device.

Comment: The dual-mode headsets are made by us also, we can change headset's firmware. Can this help us to identify the device?

Comment: Since you control the firmware, you could possibly populate the paired phone name into a BLE attribute; then your app could connect to each device and retrieve that value in order to work out which device is "the right one".  It is a bit of a kludge though

Comment: Thanks a lot. A good idea, we will try it.